Implementing Rdlc report in ASP.NET Core
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Print([FromBody] Base64Model model)
{
    // Create the view model and pass the Base64 PDF data 
    var ViewModel = new ReportViewModel { Base64Pdf = model.Base64Pdf }; 

    // Return the view and pass the ViewModel 
    return View(ViewModel);
}

This hit from web forms something like
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("https://localhost:7149/Home/Print", content);

I am not getting base64 string in my view code it only pass in
@{ var base64Pdf = Model?.Base64Pdf; } 

base64Pdf have base64 string but after that scope null
